# How to use a sprite as an input rollover?

Tags: javascript, css, input

Is there any quick and easy way to use a sprite to create a rollover on an input?

I am not that familiar with inputs and specifically what you do regarding rollovers on inputs. I understand using sprites on  tags. I also get the concept of using Javascript onMouseOut with two images, but I would really prefer to use a sprite. They seem to work best and I won't have to worry about flickering.

Here is an image I am working with:
[image]

Here is the code I am working with:

```
<style>
#newsletterSubmit{background:url(/Images/Buttons/submit.png) 0 0 no-repeat;display:block;width:90px;height:50px;text-indent:-9000px;}
</style>

 <input id="newsletterSubmit" type="image" src="Images/Buttons/Submit.png" onmouseover="document.getElementById('newsletterSubmit').style.backgroundPosition='0px -50px';" onmouseover="document.getElementById('newsletterSubmit').style.backgroundPosition='0px 0px';" />
```

Comment: Can you provide any more details? What does you current CSS, HTML, and sprite image look like (assuming you've put a little effort into this)? Does it have to be quick ***and*** easy or is just easy OK?

Comment: I am sorry, I am just looking for a way to add a rollover on a submit button for my form.

Comment: <input value="Send email" type="submit" />

Comment: If you know the basic concept of sprites you should be able to get something started at least. If not, you can read about it here: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ ...and [else](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+sprites)[where](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+sprites). What does your sprite look like and what is the effect you're going for?

Comment: I get the concept of sprites and understand how to use them on an <a> tag, however, they don't seem to work the same with a submit button on a form... Or Maybe I am wrong. I will post my code and let you look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need javascript or `onmouseover`, it can all be done with CSS. Here is a simple example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

```
input {
    display:block;
    text-indent:-9000px;
    border:0;
    padding:0;

    background:url(/Images/Buttons/submit.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    width:90px;
    height:50px;
}

input:hover {
   /* Move the background image up 50px (height of button) */
   background-position:0 -50px;  
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ihafib

You'll want to check the coordinates of your sprite and crop it appropriately to make sure everything lines up correctly.

Comment: Ok, so you can do it exactly like you do for an <a> tag! Perfect! I guess the only difference is that you would have to call the submit input out by a specific class or ID!  Thanks for the help. I guess I was trying to make it harder than it needed to be..

Comment: Yes, just change the selector from `input` to `#newsletterSubmit`. Side note: in your previous code where you were using `document.getElementById('newsletterSubmit')` you could have just used `this` - but you don't need js for this - just thought I'd let you know about it.